# How do I fix this xml and xsl code because it doesn't work

Tags: html, xml, xslt

First attempt to code xml and use xsl for html output.

I took the W3 examples and modified them for my needs but I've missed something as looking at the xml in a browser does work correctly.  None of the html code shows in the browser but the items info from the xml shows as long list.

What shows in browser:

```
SCALARADD Image1inSCALARADD Add one value to an image. A B A same as B allowed redLevel, greenLevel, blueLevel TRIMFILL Image1inTRIMFILL Trim an image and fill the trim area. A B A same as B allowed trimTopIndex, trimBottomIndex, trimLeftIndex, trimRightIndex fillRedLevel, fillGreenLevel, fillBlueLevel
```

Here is the xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="routines.xsl"?>

<family>
  <Image1in>
    <routine>SCALARADD</routine>
    <symbolic> Image1inSCALARADD </symbolic>
    <operation> Add one value to an image. </operation>
    <inputLayer1> A </inputLayer1>
    <inputLayer2></inputLayer2>
    <outputLayer1> B </outputLayer1>
    <commentLayer> A same as B allowed </commentLayer>
    <inputLong></inputLong>
    <inputDouble> redLevel, greenLevel, blueLevel </inputDouble>
    <outputLong></outputLong>
    <outputDouble></outputDouble>
    <comment>  </comment>
  </Image1in>

  <Image1in>
    <routine>TRIMFILL</routine>
    <symbolic> Image1inTRIMFILL </symbolic>
    <operation> Trim an image and fill the trim area. </operation>
    <inputLayer1> A </inputLayer1>
    <inputLayer2></inputLayer2>
    <outputLayer1> B </outputLayer1>
    <commentLayer> A same as B allowed </commentLayer>
    <inputLong> trimTopIndex, trimBottomIndex, trimLeftIndex, trimRightIndex </inputLong>
    <inputDouble> fillRedLevel, fillGreenLevel, fillBlueLevel </inputDouble>
    <outputLong></outputLong>
    <outputDouble></outputDouble>
    <comment>  </comment>
  </Image1in>

</family>
```

Here is the xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Routines</h2>
        <table border="2">

          <tr bgcolor="#7f7f7f">
            <td style="text-align:left">Title</td>
            <td style="text-align:left">Symbol</td>
            <td style="text-align:left">Operation</td>
            <td style="text-align:left">Input Layer 1</td>
          </tr>

          <xsl:for-each select="family/Image1In">
            <xsl:sort select="routine"/>

            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="routine"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="symbolic"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="operation"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="inputLayer1"/></td>
            </tr>

          </xsl:for-each>

        </table>
      </body>
    </html>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I appreciate any help someone can share.  Spent whole weekend try to fix.
Regards,
RONC

Answer (score 0):

A browser is not a good environment for testing XSLT. As it happens, your XSLT has a mistake of using:

```
<xsl:for-each select="family/Image1In">
```

instead of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="family/Image1in">
```

XML is case-sensitive, and your expression selects nothing.

However, you should still be seeing the header row of the table. What you see instead - the raw text of of the XML - suggests that your browser is applying the "same origin" security rule and blocking the request for the stylesheet.

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this code** `<xsl:for-each select="family/Image1in">` insted of `<xsl:for-each select="family/Image1In">` **Or** if you want to remove both leading and trailing space remove use `normalize-space()`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Routines</h2>
                <table border="2">

                    <tr bgcolor="#7f7f7f">
                        <td style="text-align:left">Title</td>
                        <td style="text-align:left">Symbol</td>
                        <td style="text-align:left">Operation</td>
                        <td style="text-align:left">Input Layer 1</td>
                    </tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="family/Image1in">
                        <xsl:sort select="routine"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(routine)"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(symbolic)"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(operation)"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(inputLayer1)"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

DEMO: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEv5

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sir, I have change Image1In insted-of Image1in but miss the explain write and normalize-space()  use for remove the leading and trailing white-space because fetch the value in a table. If generate the txt file then no required normalize-space().

Comment: Changing Image1In to Image1in and use of xsltfiddle tool solves my problem as I get usable html output.  Thanks for the quick help.  RONC

Comment: If I were not going to use xsltfiddle, how else could I run the xml-xsl to get an html output?  I removed the normalize-space() as the xml was not supposed to have the leading and trailing spaces.  Again thanks for the practical help.  RONC

Comment: @Ronc, You can try Transform Editors: Oxygen XML Editor, Altova, etc.. or use in xml <?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='filename.xsl'?> More Details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xml-tools/how-to-execute-an-xslt-transformation-from-the-xml-editor?view=vs-2019

Comment: I have xml <?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='filename.xsl'?> in the xml file but no browser works.  I'll look at visual studio.  RONC

Comment: You can check xsl file name or try select the file open-with Explorer.

Comment: Works in both EDGE and IE but not Firefox or Chrome.  I'll use EDGE.  Last comment.  RONC